# Unable to detect proper document offsetHeight when enabling modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Like the title says, I am unable to detect a change in the document's offsetHeight using Javascript when enabling/opening a modal. It works well without the modal i.e it'll return the correct pixels if there are changes in the offsetHeight.

What I want is for javascript to detect the modals offsetHeight and return the correct pixels, which it currently isn't. It would be really helpful if I knew as to why this issue occurs, aswell as a fix for this issue.

I've posted a test code for this issue below. You would be able to test it better on jsfiddle or locally. The offsetHeight will be displayed in the console log.

https://jsfiddle.net/z0euqgLj/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2 id="appendme">Some Text</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="appendtext()">Add more text</button>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2><h2>Some Text</h2>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<script>
//Check the Document offsetHeight every 500 milliseconds
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval(checkH, 500);   
});

//Check the offsetHeight
function checkH(){
 var offsetH = document.body.offsetHeight;
 console.log(offsetH);
}

function appendtext(){
    $("#appendme").append('<br>Some Text');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you expected to get when the modal is open? Since the modal is `absolute` positioned it doesn't part of the document flow.

Comment: Hello, I've updated the post with my expectations. Thanks for letting me know as to why this is happening.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want to get the body's height but if the body doesn't have the full window height, you want the window height. If so, `Math.max(window.innerHeight, document.body.scrollHeight)` - https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/v5b8au7c/1/.